# How to read the source code without restrictions?

Tags: abap

There is a task reading the source codes of ABAP reports. I usually use the function: RFC_READ_DEVELOPMENT_OBJECT or RFC_READ_REPORT. But these functions have some limits: in the line should not exceed 72 characters (if more then error). 
72 characters because table QTAB = 72 characters on line

Comment: Do you have to use RFC? If so, do you have a way to write your own function module?

Comment: Yes. It is not desirable, but as I understand it no other way.In its function needs to be done more characters in a line? (For example 200, but that if the line more characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As vwegert suggests in his comment, you could write your own remote-enabled function module. It is very easy. Refer to the following blog post for a suggestion: http://ceronio.net/2009/06/improved-abap-source-code-search/

The function makes use of the [`READ REPORT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapread_report.htm) statement to read source code of a program.

```
DATA: itab TYPE TABLE OF string,
      prog TYPE syrepid.

prog = 'SAPMSSY0'.

READ REPORT prog INTO itab.

IF sy-subrc = 0.
  " source code unit is read successfully into "itab"
ENDIF.
```

The only drawback is if you don't have a developer key.